# How to catch commit action with spring aspects

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm new with Spring Aspects and I'm trying to catch de commit action in a @Transactional methods.

This is my class structure:

```
FacadeClass
   |_____ ServiceClass
             |_____ DaoClass
```

The 3 clases are transactional

```
 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        |_____  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
                       |_____  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
```

So, I'm trying to launch some events in the Service, but only if the transaction is commited. The idea is to notify other application with the updated objet, but this changes only were made if the transaction works.

Is it possible to catch the commit action with the updated objet in an aspect? Even if the transaction was oppened in the facade?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest not to use AOP for that, use a `TransactionSynchronization` instead and register that, implement the `afterCommit` to do what you want. If you need the object you might want use use a JPA event listener instead.

Comment: I have found this [example](http://azagorneanu.blogspot.com.es/2013/06/transaction-synchronization-callbacks.html), very interesting.